# How to make rate limiter in FastApi

Tags: python, fastapi, rate-limiting

I want to rate limiter endpoint in my app with 10 requests per second. I have seen this question [Ratelimit in Fastapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65491184/ratelimit-in-fastapi), but i cant understand how i should do in my project, because i have multiple files.
My main.py

```
from .router import router

from fastapi import FastAPI


def get_application() -> FastAPI:
    application = FastAPI()

    application.include_router(router)

    return application


app = get_application()
```

and router.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/")
async def some_func(...):
    #some code
```

So, how can i rate limiter my methods from router.py?

Comment: no, it doesnt, because i need to add @limiter.limit() at router.py if it possible